# WebDav as Sharepoint like DMS

Tags: php, javascript, apache, webdav

I'm trying to implement a Sharepoint like Document Management System with WebDAV.

I configured everything how it should be

```
DavLockDB WebDAV/Locks
  <Location /uploads>
    DAV on
    SVNPath Path\to\SVN
    SVNAutoversioning on
    SVNPathAuthz off
    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "My WebDAV"
    Require valid-user
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIOmitDomain On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain hbs.ch
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    SSPIUsernameCase lower
    ForceType text/plain
  </Location>
```

And with a bit of Javascript I am able to open Doc's in edit mode:

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3');
obj.EditDocument(path);
```

But I still stuck on a Problem I can't handle.
The Folders for each user is dynamically generated when he loggs in the first time. 
So on he has dynamically access to some group folders wich are generated on the fly.

If he can access to those group folders belongs to some Indicators in a database.

So how can I generate this permissions to these folder on runtime ?

As far as I understand the WebDav concept I have to specify each folder in a config file.
Or I have to set the permissions on AD Level.(But that isn't practicable for me because the groups don't exists in an AD, they just exist in a DB)

Has anybody any idea, how I could solve this ?
Or another DMS wich I could use as backend ?